# Ler arquivo XML, servidor retornando erro

Tags: c#, xml, xmldocument

Escrevi um código para ler RSS feed que funciona bem. Se você acessar [esta URL](http://migalhas.com.br/rss/rss.xml) verá que retorna um XML no browser, mas ao rodar no meu código gera um erro interno no servidor e não entendo o motivo. Alguém pode me ajudar?

O código abaixo está no [dotNetFeedle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/S8bbb4). Se descomentar o segundo link e comentar o primeiro você pode ver o erro.

```
using System;
using System.Xml;

public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {

    string urlXml = "http://g1.globo.com/dynamo/tecnologia/rss2.xml";
    //string urlXml = @"http://migalhas.com.br/rss/rss.xml";

    //Cria novo documento XML local
    XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();

    //Tenta Carregar XML remoto em nosso XML local
    try
    {
        doc.Load(urlXml);
        XmlNodeList rssItems = doc.SelectNodes("//item");   

        int i = 0;
        foreach (XmlNode node in rssItems)
        {
            i++;
            Console.WriteLine(i + " - " + node["title"].InnerText);
            if(i==5)
            break;
        }    
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Erro:" + ex.Message);
    }
    //Selcecionar nós desejados usando xPath

    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tente dessa forma com WebClient

```
//string urlXml = "http://g1.globo.com/dynamo/tecnologia/rss2.xml";
string urlXml = @"http://migalhas.com.br/rss/rss.xml";

var data = "";

using (var wc = new WebClient())
{
    wc.Headers.Add("user-agent", "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; Windows NT 5.1; rv:1.9.2.4) Gecko/20100611 Firefox/3.6.4");
    data = wc.DownloadString(urlXml);                
}

var reader = new XmlTextReader(new System.IO.StringReader(data));
while (reader.Read())
{
    Console.WriteLine(reader.Value);
}
```

Comment: Funcionou. Muito obrigado

Comment: @EduardoSobrinho Maravilha, não esqueça de marcar como respondido :)

Comment: Thiago, esta é a primeira pergunta que me responderam aqui. Cliquei em um sinal de 'checked' no lado esquerdo da sua reposta. É só isso para marcar como respondida? Mais uma vez, obrigado.

Comment: @EduardoSobrinho está certinho! isso mesmo, bem vindo ao StackOverflow!